# @synthesize syntax, with and without equals sign

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, properties

if I have a property in my .h lets call it:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) foo;
```

What is the difference between synthesising like this:

```
@synthesize foo;
```

and like this:

```
@synthesize foo = _foo;
```

Thanks chaps.

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate question Martin. Although your answer in the linked question touches on what I have asked here.

Comment: You are right, your question is different, but compare [What is the difference between this 2 @synthesize Pattern and which is Recommanded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016955/what-is-the-difference-between-this-2-synthesize-pattern-and-which-is-recommand).

Comment: You’re right, that’s closer to a duplicate, but then again the accepted answer suggests to use `@synthesize foo = _foo`, which is completely redundant today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the options, I hope I got them right:

1. `@synthesize foo` uses a backing instance variable `foo`
2. `@synthesize foo = _foo` uses a backing instance variable `_foo`
3. `/* no synthesize at all */` is the same as (2)

In all cases the backing instance variable is created automatically and you get a property named `foo`. The best practice (IMHO) is the last case, there’s less code and the underscore is a nice reminder that you’re working with an instance variable (something like `self->`, just shorter).